# On-prem SharePoint 2016 trying to talk to a database that doesn't exist

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, timer-jobs

My Sharepoint 2016 server is acting flakey and constantly requiring a reboot of my database server.

I have a bunch of critical Database and Timer errors on the SharePoint server which are:

**Database Critical - 3760**

```
SQL Database 'Temp_Content' on SQL Server instance Srv-DB1\SHAREPOINT' not found.  Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Cannot open database "Temp_Content" requested by the login.  The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MYDomain\spadmin'.
```

**Timer Critical - 6398**

```
The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob (ID 089e29c0-e531-4365-9ac2-735b726a4c6b) threw an exception. More information is included below.

Cannot open database "Temp_Content" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MYDomain\spadmin'.. (Correlation=9603119f-72c0-a0f0-7b6f-633aa48a42bc)
```

The problem is....there is no database or table "Temp_Content" on the database server, so there is no way for me to grant access to it.  Any advice ?

Comment: Does `Get-SPDatabase` show this database?

Comment: Yes, it is listed when running Get-SPDatabase on the SharePoint server.  

Temp_Content             432e3b1e-4ee9-4f43-95f7-c0a7cb4febcd Content Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `Remove-SPContentDatabase "Temp_Content 432e3b1e-4ee9-4f43-95f7-c0a7cb4febcd Content Database"`.